# Return old user account folder (.000) or merge them after windows 10 update/upgrade

Tags: windows-10

After the creators fall update I noticed that my user folder account was changed from `distante` to `distante.000` keeping for some reason the original folder too. So I have

- /distante/ (with a couple of folders inside appdata)
- /distante.000/ (with all my appdata)

I have no idea if the old folder (distante) is needed. All works ok but it disturb me when i work with command line tools like npm or git. Is there a way to merge both again into `/distante/` ?

Comment: You should revert your installation back to 1703 to restore your original user profile.  You should then only upgrade to 1709 if it is offered through Windows Update.

Comment: Do you remember which folders remained in your old /distante/ folder? The ones that remained may give a clue why the directory was renamed.

Answer (score 1):

As you had mentioned that all app data are stored on new user account folder. Instead of delete the old user account folder directly, please manually re-name it, such as *distante.old*. If there is no problem after folder rename, you may try to delete it.

**Note:**
**Please back up system/important data before any change.**

Or, if you do not want to use *distante.000* folder, you may try to create a new user account, give it a local admin permission, and manually copy all data from *distante.000* to new user account folder.